# Getting the same variable in each <td> but with different values

Tags: php, function, variables

**in HTML I have:**

```
<?php $mysqli = connectDB(); ?>

<tr>
        <td class='inaltime'>1845</td>
        <td>
        <?php $length = 2000; $height = 1845; include_once 
"calculator/calculator.php"; ?>
        <?= getPrice($pretTransportPierderi); ?> 
</td>
        <td><?php $length = 2100; $height = 1845; include_once 
"calculator/calculator.php"; ?>
        <?= getPrice($pretTransportPierderi); ?> </td>
        <td><?php $length = 2200; $height = 1845; include_once 
"calculator/calculator.php"; ?>
        <?= getPrice($pretTransportPierderi); ?> </td>
    </tr>
```

As you can see, I am trying to add a different value to `$length` in each `<td>`

**calculator.php is:**

```
$pretTransportPierderi = ...; // SOME COMPLEX MATHEMATICAL FORMULAS WHERE &length and $height are included.

function getPrice($pretTransportPierderi)
{
    $pretFinal = $pretTransportPierderi + ($pretTransportPierderi * 0.2);
    return round($pretFinal, 2);
}
```

In the first `<td>` it shows the sum, but in the second and third  will show the value from first `<td>`, not the values 3945 and 4045 as it should.

How to create the code in HTML, in order to see diferrent `<?= getPrice($length , $height); ?>` value?

The included file should get the $length and $height from the HTML.

Example:

[image]

Comment: what is $pretTransportPierderi variable ?

Comment: First include_once will include one time your file, then the file will not include anymore after the first time, seconde you don't use the variables defined just before your function call

Comment: `$pretTransportPierderi` ignore it. I edited the post.

Comment: @MacBooc then it should be only `include "";` ?

Comment: yep but normally you include it one time in the top on the file for example.

Comment: because it's just a function in your file

Comment: you are calculating twice the height ... look your first getPrice($height , $height )

Comment: @SimosFasouliotis it was just a mistake here, not in code. Edited it.

Comment: @macbook i can't include it in the top of the file, because i need `$length` and `$height` from the `<td>'s`

Comment: @BogdanC are these numbers correct as expected output ? 1845 2369 2469 2569

Comment: @SimosFasouliotis ignore the numbers from the picture table. In my real code, there are complex mathematical formulas. I just shorted the code to give you an example.

Comment: you don't need the $lenght $height to include the file, it's just a function that you call after. and actually this code works fine in my local

Comment: The included file should get the $length and $height from the HTML table.

Comment: @MacBooc how did you make it please? Post an answer. Thank you.

Comment: I can explain with more details if you need it @BogdanC

Comment: The code you provided works as expected - maybe some other thing in getPrice is giving wrong result then since you show us a simplified version only?

Comment: I edited the calculator.php code in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to include_once() once. :-P

Your code appears to work! Look here and see, all I have done is remove the include once: https://3v4l.org/4iMb1

```
?php
function getPrice($length, $height)
{
$pretFinal = $length + ($height* 0.2);
return $pretFinal;
}
?>

<tr>
        <td class='inaltime'>1845</td>
        <td>
        <?php $length = 2000; $height = 1845; ?>
        <?= getPrice($length, $height ); ?> 
</td>
        <td><?php $length = 2100; $height = 1845;?>
        <?= getPrice($length , $height); ?> </td>
        <td><?php $length = 2200; $height = 1845; ?>
        <?= getPrice($length , $height); ?> </td>
    </tr>
```

Output :

```
<tr> <td class='inaltime'>1845</td> <td> 2369 </td> <td> 2469 </td> <td> 2569 </td> </tr>
```

Comment: I see that, and now you have broke it worse. You don't even refer to $length and $height, opting instead for values already set from some other function which you haven't shared details of.

Comment: The entire calculator.php is dependent of $length and $height. For each <td> I am trying to get the $length and $height and echo the result of that function.

Comment: But that function no longer takes your newly set width and height. Does $pretTransportPierderi ever change? Or does it run once?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php include "/calculator.php"; ?>
<tr>
$height = 1845;
<td>
    <?php $sum = 2000 + $height ;  ?>
    <?= getPrice($sum); ?>
</td>
<td><?php $sum = 2100 + $height ;  ?>
    <?= getPrice($sum); ?></td>
<td><?php $sum = 2200 + $height ;  ?>
    <?= getPrice($sum); ?> </td>
</tr>
```

don't upvote this it just for explain.

And this code work already fine in my local.

While your function is in a file you just need to include one time the file in the top to use it (even they are one billion other function in the file)

then if you need the data of your database it's the same way

```
<?= getPrice($table['lenght'], $table['height']) ?>
```

EDIT:

Actually i think to do this calculation by your way isn't really good because you include a file only for change a variable that you can change directly in the loop to create your table or just add a new function to create this variable seperate the logic to the view like

```
//calculator.php
function PreparingMyVariable($lenght, $height)
{
    //do what i need for my calculation function
}
function getPrice($pretTransportPierderi)
{
    $pretFinal = $pretTransportPierderi + ($pretTransportPierderi * 0.2); 
    return round($pretFinal, 2); 
}
```

then

```
<?php include "/calculator.php"; ?>
//lot of thing

<tr>
<?php $height = 1845; ?>
<td>
    <?php $lenght = 6843132;
          $sum = PreparingMyVariable($lenght, $height);  ?>
    <?= getPrice($sum); ?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php $lenght = 6843132;
          $sum = PreparingMyVariable($lenght, $height);  ?>
    <?= getPrice($sum); ?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php $lenght = 6843132;
          $sum = PreparingMyVariable($lenght, $height);  ?>
    <?= getPrice($sum); ?> 
</td>
</tr>
```

And you can even do this in one function calling other function to seperate you actual calculation function

Comment: actually, my function is like this:
`$pretTransportPierderi = $pretCuTransport + $pretPierderi;
    function getPrice($pretTransportPierderi)
    {
     $pretFinal = $pretTransportPierderi + ($pretTransportPierderi * 0.2);
     return round($pretFinal, 2);
    }`

Comment: My function does not have included $length and $height.

Comment: hmmm then you question is not entirely explained. but if you need this i'll edit my answer but i think you try somethink by a bad way

Comment: My bad. modifiying the function for an easy interpretation, screw up your thinking.

Comment: i edited my answer, but i'll explain why it's a bad way to do like you do

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function PreparingMyVariable() in

Comment: And `Notice: Undefined variable: length in /hom` and Notice: Undefined variable: height in /hom

Comment: Oh i see.. you mean to put all my above from calculator.php in a function

Comment: yep which you include it one time int the top

Comment: keep in mind that factorization is your friend ! create 10 function even for one calculation isn't crazy and change variable dynamicly and use more function is a good way to do this kind of things

Comment: @BogdanC this helped you ?